# Insmod error in grub: symbol not found:grub_realidt

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grubrescue

I have a dual boot PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and then to 13.04 and since then I have not been able to boot because the PC goes into grub rescue with the error "File not found".

I have tried the following steps:

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
insmod linux
```

I get error:

```
symbol not found : 'grub_realidt'.
```

if I do insmod normal, I get error

```
symbol not found : 'grub_disk_dev_list'
```

I have two partitions containing linux file system: (hd0,msdos5) and (hd0,msdos6). They were mountpoints for / and /boot respectively.

I have searched for this error, and found some "solved" threads. But all of them are using Live USB to get in grub prompt. I don't have access to one, and was hoping to be able to solve the issue without a flash drive.

Please help...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is shown when you do `ls (hd0,msdos5)/` and `ls (hd0,msdos6)/`?

Comment: ls (hd0,msdos5)/ shows /boot /home vmlinuz initrd.img
ls (hd0,msdos6)/ shows /grub lost+found and many generic image files

Answer (score 0):

From [Troubleshooting Preparation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#GRUB%202%20Troubleshooting%20Preparation) it should be possible to fix this from command line. But the commands I found are a bit different than you have in your question. So...

- Do a

  ```
  ls (hd0,msdos5)/ 
  ls (hd0,msdos6)/
  ```
- If you see `grub` then do a `set prefix="(hd0,msdos5)/grub"` where 5 needs to be changed to correct number.
- If you see `boot` then do a

  ```
  set prefix="(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub"
  set root="(hd0,msdos5)"
  ```

  where 5 needs to be changed to correct number.
- After changing prefix you need to do a

  ```
  insmod normal
  normal
  ```

  and reboot.

Comment: set prefix="(hd0,msdos5)/grub" doesn't work since my *.mod files are not present in this directory for some reason. So, insmod gives file not found error.

Comment: This is the only method I know and I am afraid you will need a live cd...